# Jodatime DateTimeFormatter need print GMT time instead of UTC

Tags: java, jodatime, datetime-format

I write this formatter :

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
private static final String FORMAT_RFC_1123_DATE_TIME = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";
private final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormat = forPattern(FORMAT_RFC_1123_DATE_TIME).withLocale(US).withZone(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(timeZone));
date.toString(dateTimeFormat)
```

The conversion is fine, but it writes `Sun, 06 Nov 1994 07:49:37 UTC` instead of `Sun, 06 Nov 1994 07:49:37 GMT`.

I know UTC is the right ouput, but I really need with GMT.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: You might just replace parsed 'UTC`-suffix by 'GMT' after parsing (as workaround because Joda-Time does not support the term GMT).

Answer (score 4):

I have tried the following code and it worked:

```
date.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("GMT"))
    .toString("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
```

My joda library version is 2.9.1 by the way.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though JodaTime doesn't support that. If you try

```
org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))
```

You actually end up with `UTC`. The javadoc from `DateTimeZone` states:

> This library only uses the term UTC.

You could probably subclass `DateTimeZone` yourself and get what you need, but from what I can tell otherwise, JodaTime won't do what you're trying to do. Below is an example, although I do not claim that it works in any way shape or form.

```
public class GMTDTZ extends DateTimeZone {
    public GMTDTZ() { super("GMT"); }

    @Override public String getNameKey(long instant) { return null; }

    @Override public int getOffset(long instant) { return 0; }

    @Override public int getStandardOffset(long instant) { return 0; }

    @Override public boolean isFixed() { return true;}

    @Override public long nextTransition(long instant) { return instant; }

    @Override public long previousTransition(long instant) { return instant; }

    @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof DateTimeZone)) return false;
        return (((DateTimeZone) o).getID().equals("GMT"));
    }
}
```